# targetSdkVersion vs. minSdkVersion: configChanges

Tags: android

I want to avoid Activity restarts when screen orientation changes. In older sdk versions it was done by `configChanges="orientation"` (in the manifest). In newer versions `screenSize` was added.

My minSdk is 8, the targetSdk is 17 and I find myself in a weird situation: I cannot put screenSize into configChanges (because of the minSdk) but my phone (4.1) will then destroy any activity on orientation change (because of the targetSdk).

Is there any way out? Can I somehow prevent this destruction without having to target an outdated Sdk (but still keeping it as an option in the minSdk)?

Comment: "I cannot put screenSize into configChanges" did you actually try that?

Comment: *"In newer versions screenSize was added"* -> so build against any version since this attribute was introduced, meaning API level 13+. Also, don't forget to add a pipe character inbetween the two options: [`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).

Comment: What is your project Build Target?  Build Target != targetSDK

Comment: @Henry - of course I tried, I wouldn't have asked otherwise.

Comment: @MH (and Henry) - The build target is currently API 10 (so I could see it also in a 2.x version as I don't have a real phone with such an old system). The problem is that  I can't have the targetSDK set to 17 and use screenSize as well and minSDK 8 (or anything below 13) at the same time. I want to see it work in older versions too. I thought I'd be able to write the code and then choose the build target only when the final version was done...

Comment: @Malis: As far as I know, your assumption is not correct. You *can* add the `screenSize` attribute in the manifest and still run the app without problems on pre level 13 devices. Just make sure you build against API level 13 or higher. On older devices that flag is simply ignored.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem and as he is explaining I can not put screenSize in configChanges as eclipse fires xml parse error because it can not interpret screenSize as correct option for configChanges. Strange factor is that os ignores configChanges with orientation value (and restarts activity) only if i specify android:targetSdkVersion above 12. But on the same machine if i specify targetSdkVersion 12 or less it does not restart activity.

Answer (score 0):

You may leave your `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` as you currently have them (8 and 17 in your example).

In order to be able to put `screenSize` into `configChanges`, change this line

`target=android-someapinumber`

in the `project.properties` file. Choose `someapinumber` as the android version where `screenSize` first appeared (e.g., API 13).

Although you asked for a specific "screenSize" problem, this solution applies to all similar situations where you want to support older devices, but at the same time you must use newer features. In this particular case, "screenSize" will be ignored by older devices that do not know this property, so you don't have to worry about backward compatibility. In other cases, you may have to add conditions in your source code like shown below to ensure in runtime that your app will not use features that are not available in a given (older) android version.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
{
    // Code that uses features available in LOLLIPOP and newer
    // versions of android, while the app also runs on older versions
    // and supports them because of android:minSdkVersion.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ah I finally figured out solution:

As far as we cant affect "known suggested solution" with screenSize property **as eclipse fires xml parse error on screenSize** when we specify android:configChanges="screenSize", if we specify in targetSdkVersion 12 or less android os will not restart activity on orientation change. (Also I did now know and was using targetSdkVersion for identifying maximum supported sdk version. But as I researched again for this there is maxSdkVersion.)

So by this settings:

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="12" 
android:maxSdkVersion="17"

...

android:configChanges="orientation|..."
```

Os will not restart activity on orientation change and application will still support minimum and maximum sdk versions but will run in compatibility mode with sdk 12 which is highest version of sdk not restarting activity which will solve the problem above.

Comment: Won't this just force users with an API > 12 to render at 12 then API > 17 = no install.  Not so sure this is a fix.